styled-component: Elegant way to trigger child style from parent
I have a Parent wrapping a Child. Upon Parent:hover, I want to trigger the Child:hover effect.

Desire 1: Parent should not have to know/care about what the Child is made of, or how it is styled.
Desire 2: Child should not have to know/care how it is used.

solution 1: Reference the child in the parent
const Child1 = styled.div`
  background: blue;
  &:hover {
    background: green;
  }
`;

const Parent1 = styled.div`
  &:hover {
    ${Child1} {
      // Issue: Parent needs to know how Child1 is made of, and what style it uses.
      // In addition, it creates a double source of truth.
      // Breaks Desire 1
      background: green;
    }
  }
`;

solution 2: Reference the parent in the child
const Parent2 = styled.div``;

const Child2 = styled.div`
  background: blue;
  &:hover {
    // Issue: Child needs to know how it is used.
    // Breaks Desire 2
    background: green;
  }
  ${Parent2}:hover & {
    background: green;
  }
`;

solution 3: Activate a child prop from the parent
const Child3 = styled.div<{ $hover?: boolean }>`
  background: blue;
  &:hover,
  ${(p) => p.$hover && '&'} {
    background: green;
  }
`;

const Parent3 = styled.div`
  &:hover {
    // Issue: This magic function doesnt seem to exist
    ${setAnyChildrenProps(Child3, (c) => (c.$hover = true))}
  }
`;

Does styled-components have something to deal with this?
Thanks a bunch.
